# Need help identifying font in this logo

Tags: font-identification

Looking for the font of the word 'technology' in [this site's](http://www.openminds.com/technology) logo:

[image]

Comment: welcome to GD.  do you mind stating what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

The font is [Gitchgitch](http://www.dafont.com/gitchgitch.font). Hope this helps somebody.

Here the samples for capital letters, same as letters:

[image]